# Generation of NPM package from Scala.js project

Tags: scala, npm, sbt, scala.js

Having a Scala.js project at destination to pure javascript developers (with all JSExport ok), is there an already existing way to automatically generate a NPM package that can be publish to a remote repository and use by those developpers?

I have a Scala.js project whose goal is to be used by pure javascript developpers. Everything is developed, including the export to use the library from javascript. After compilation I have two js file: the lib itself (xx_opt.js), and the local js dependancies into a xx_jsdeps.js.

So far so good, but is there a way to (almost) automatically generate a package (NPM?) that can be publish to a remote repository and used by pure javascript developpers as any other JS library? 
I found a lot of things to use NPM dependencies, but not the inverse operation. 
Did I miss something, or must be it done "by hand"? Il may be trivial, but I must admit I'm not very familiar with the JS and NPM world, so any tip or best practices may be useful.

Comment: There is a very old proof-of-concept at https://www.npmjs.com/package/scala-node (sources at https://github.com/rockymadden/scala-node). It uses a completely obsolete version of Scala.js, but that shouldn't matter for you. You just need to take the npm-related bits.

Comment: Well it is interesting (and informative). Thanks. However it requires to manage by hand all the configuration with some specific scripts. Not really the automatic way I was hoping for. In the end I end up creating a specific task in my build.sbt to prepare the npm package with the desired arborescence and copy the needed files in it. After that I just have to do a npm publish to actually publish the package.

Comment: Since you managed to get something working, perhaps you could answer your own question with your solution, so that others trying to the same thing can benefit from what you went through?

Comment: Ok. See the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the task I added in my build.sbt. Maybe not the smartest way to do it, but it is enough for my needs. It create some folders in the destination folder (here target/npm/) and copy the needed files into them. It also generate the package.json file using the meta data present in the build.sbt (package name, version, author, ...) .

```
val npmTargetDir = s"target/npm/" // where to generate npm
val npmConf = "npm_config" // directory with static files for NPM package
val npmTask = taskKey[Unit](s"Create npm package arborescence in $npmTargetDir")


npmTask := {
  // JS libraries must first be generated
  (Compile / fastOptJS).value 
  (Compile / fullOptJS).value 

  import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
  import java.nio.file.Files.copy
  import java.nio.file.Paths.get
  import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

  implicit def toPath (filename: String) = get(filename)

  def copyToDir(filePathName:String, dirName:String) = {
    val fileName = new File(filePathName).getName
    copy (s"$filePathName", s"$dirName/$fileName", REPLACE_EXISTING)
  }

  val libName = name.value.toLowerCase()    

  val inputDir = "target/scala-2.12"
  val targetDir = s"$npmTargetDir/$libName"    
  val sourceDir = "source/js"
  val distDir = "dist/js"
  val demoCssDir = "demo/css"

  // create arborescence
  new File(targetDir).mkdirs()
  List(demoCssDir, distDir, sourceDir).foreach(d => new File(s"$targetDir/$d").mkdirs())

  // copy static files
  //copyToDir(s"$npmConf/package.json", targetDir)
  copyToDir(s"$npmConf/licence.txt", targetDir)
  copyToDir(s"$npmConf/exampleJSFastOpt.html", targetDir)
  copyToDir(s"$npmConf/exampleJSFullOpt.html", targetDir)
  copyToDir(s"$npmConf/style.css", s"$targetDir/$demoCssDir")

  // copy optimized js library
  val fileDist = List(s"$libName-opt.js", s"$libName-jsdeps.min.js", s"$libName-opt.js.map")
  for(file <- fileDist) {
    println(s"copy file $inputDir/$file")
    copy(s"$inputDir/$file", s"$targetDir/$distDir/$file", REPLACE_EXISTING)
  }

  // copy non optimized js library (for debug purpose)
  val fileSource = List(s"$libName-fastopt.js", s"$libName-jsdeps.js", s"$libName-fastopt.js.map")
  for(file <- fileSource) {
    println(s"copy file $file")
    copy(s"$inputDir/$file", s"$targetDir/$sourceDir/$file", REPLACE_EXISTING)
  }

  val packageJson = s"""{
  "name": "$libName",
  "version": "${version.value.toString}",
  "description": "${description.value.toString}",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "sbt test"
  },
  "main": "$distDir",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://...git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "scalajs"
  ],
  "author": "${author}",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN licence.txt",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://..."
  },
  "homepage": "https://...",
  "dependencies": {}
}"""

  println(packageJson)
  Files.write(Paths.get(s"$targetDir/package.json"), packageJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

  println(s"NPM arborescence for package created in $npmTargetDir")
}
```